# Get error when different blog api's are requested

Tags: node.js, rest, backend

I used postman to test my rest api. the api are written over expressjs framewwork

I get a route not found error when i call view,edit api's. but when i call "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/blogs/all "
i get list of all the blogs present.

i am not able to figure out whats the error.

github link for blog-api code:  https://github.com/naikvaibhav/blog-api.git

Comment: Ok, please let us know the url you typed for edit api.
I looked around your code and it seems `app.put(baseUrl+'/:blogId/edit',blogController.editBlog);` is your edit api.

Comment: ya that's correct

Comment: then please comment request url and error code. It would be much better to add it in your question (request url for edit api/error message inside postman).